# jsp- how to assign input value into another variable I would like to use later?

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

the problem is

when I say:

```
alert(parseInt(document.frmFuture.txtDays.value) + 7);
```

(value is number that user input) it shows fine.

but when I say:

```
var tmp = document.frmFuture.txtDays.value;
alert(tmp + 7);
```

it gives me undefined.

Actually, I want to do some cals later using the input number. But it looks like impossible? how can i do that?

Comment: Is the code *exactly* like you posted? When is the JS executed in each case? Also, this is nothing to do with JSP (so far), just HTML and JS.

Comment: this is the part I picked up from the whole code.. I am not quite sure, but when i debug, the error 
(which is the infor: undefine) shows just because these two lines code, so i wonder how can i fix that?

Comment: could you post more of the code?

Comment: what happened to `parseInt` ?

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the `parseInt`.

```
var tmp = parseInt(document.frmFuture.txtDays.value);
alert(tmp + 7);
```

Now it should work.